Can't import or create keys in Kleopatra in Arch Linux using KDE (x11)
I'm still new to linux, so please give me time if you need something from me.
As the title says I cannot create new key pairs or import existing keys into Kleopatra 3.2.0.240501 (24.05.1). I've just done a system update (sudo pacman -Syu) before trying out the included application. When I try to import an existing key this error comes up:
/home/keys/xxxxxxxxxx_SECRET.asc(I18N_ARGUMENT_MISSING) (imported with gpg(I18N_ARGUMENT_MISSING))
Audit log is empty.

/home/keys/xxxxxxxxxx_SECRET.asc(I18N_ARGUMENT_MISSING) (imported with gpgsm(I18N_ARGUMENT_MISSING))
Audit log is empty. 

(key name is censored by me, but the correct name is being used)
Creating a new key pair gives this result:
The creation of a new OpenPGP certificate failed.

Error: /SQL library used incorrectly/

I've tried importing the same key in Windows or creating a new key pair and it worked without problems there (all keys were created with windows so far)
Thank you for your help

I am receiving the same error and added the observation to this bugticket: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=490584
Did you find any solution?
